# Xcode won't let me use simulator

Tags: xcode

Xcode is not letting me use simulator to build apps. I tried deleting and re-downloading and still has same problem: Failed with Exit Code 1.
I just started a bootcamp for iOS 12 and Swift a couple weeks ago, so I am still figuring most things out. What do I need to do to fix this?

CopySwiftLibs

```
/Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse\ Mythology.app (in target: Norse Mythology)
    cd /Users/Zike/Library/Autosave\ Information/Norse\ Mythology
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    export SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk
    builtin-swiftStdLibTool --copy --verbose --sign 1BB855B5EC2A7454DBE0F820EE93868FB82CABB7 --scan-executable /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse\ Mythology.app/Norse\ Mythology --scan-folder /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse\ Mythology.app/Frameworks --scan-folder /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse\ Mythology.app/PlugIns --platform iphoneos --toolchain /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain --destination /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse\ Mythology.app/Frameworks --strip-bitcode --resource-destination /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse\ Mythology.app --resource-library libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib --strip-bitcode-tool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip --emit-dependency-info /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Norse\ Mythology.build/Debug-iphoneos/Norse\ Mythology.build/SwiftStdLibToolInputDependencies.dep

Requested Swift ABI version based on scanned binaries: 6
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftDarwin.dylib to /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse Mythology.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftDarwin.dylib -r -o /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse Mythology.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftMetal.dylib to /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse Mythology.app/Frameworks/libswiftMetal.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftMetal.dylib -r -o /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse Mythology.app/Frameworks/libswiftMetal.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftos.dylib to /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse Mythology.app/Frameworks/libswiftos.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftos.dylib -r -o /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse Mythology.app/Frameworks/libswiftos.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCore.dylib to /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse Mythology.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCore.dylib -r -o /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse Mythology.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCoreImage.dylib to /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse Mythology.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCoreImage.dylib -r -o /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse Mythology.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib to /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse Mythology.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib -r -o /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse Mythology.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftUIKit.dylib to /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse Mythology.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftUIKit.dylib -r -o /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse Mythology.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib to /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse Mythology.app/Frameworks/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib -r -o /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse Mythology.app/Frameworks/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib to /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse Mythology.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib -r -o /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse Mythology.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib to /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse Mythology.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib -r -o /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse Mythology.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftDispatch.dylib to /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse Mythology.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftDispatch.dylib -r -o /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse Mythology.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib to /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse Mythology.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib -r -o /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse Mythology.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftFoundation.dylib to /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse Mythology.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftFoundation.dylib -r -o /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse Mythology.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos/libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib to /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse Mythology.app/libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib
Probing signature of /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse Mythology.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
/usr/bin/codesign -r- --display /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse Mythology.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
/Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse Mythology.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib: code object is not signed at all

Codesigning /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse Mythology.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 1BB855B5EC2A7454DBE0F820EE93868FB82CABB7 --verbose /Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse Mythology.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib
/Users/Zike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Norse_Mythology-ayyvdkolhkmofsczhivtkebjinmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Norse Mythology.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib: errSecInternalComponent
```

error: Failed with exit code 1

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  What is this output from?  Have you tried cleaning your Derived Data folder?  It looks like "libswiftDarwin.dylib: errSecInternalComponent" is your error.

Comment: That worked, thank you so much. Although I don't entirely understand how it happened and why it caused that?

Comment: I'm glad it worked.  When weird stuff like this happens, the first thing I do is clean that folder.  I'll add this as an answer so you can accept it.  That will help other people who might have a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often, problems like this can be resolved by cleaning (deleting the contents of) the Derived Data folder.

[Source](https://macpaw.com/how-to/clear-xcode-cache):

## How to clear Xcode cache manually

## 1. Clean the build

Tip: If you’re trying to fix a problem with Xcode crashing, it’s worth cleaning the project build first. This will get rid of the current build and create a new one next time you run the code.

1. With the project open in code, go to the menu bar, choose `Product -> Clean` or:
2. With the project open, press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>.

## 2. Clean out the build folder

To clean out the build folder, and get rid of cache files, do the following:

1. In the Code project, click on the Product menu while holding down <kbd>Option</kbd> and choose `Clean build folder`, or:
2. Press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>.

## 3. Reset Simulator content and settings

If neither of the steps above resolves your problem, try resetting the simulator content and settings:

Go to the menu and choose `iOS Simulator`, then click `Reset Content and Settings`.

## 4. Delete derived data

If you’re still having problems, try deleting derived data, which will force Xcode to recreate it when you next run it.

1. In the menu, choose `Window -> Organizer`.
2. Now select `Projects -> Select your project`.
3. Choose the project whose derived data you want to delete.
4. In the window that opens, you’ll see see the Derived Data folder listed, along with its Finder path.
5. To the right of the folder, there’s a `Delete` button. Press it.

Now, delete the module cache.

1. Go to: `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache`.
2. Drag the files from the ModuleCache folder to the Trash and empty it.